# Running Flutter on IOS - Module 'cloud_firestore' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I have tried all of the solutions I could find on Stack Overflow for this problem. When I build my flutter app, I get this error:

```
Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
```

I am using flutter 2.10.4 and xcode 13.3

Here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '15.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can try this one might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015602/fatal-error-module-cloud-firestore-not-found

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work :(

Comment: Just restart your pc once then try again and after restart it's not working and if you are using Android Studio then try 
--> Invalid Cache and Restart   option that Rebuild your project and clear old caches that might be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the helpful but its still not working